# non-mutually exclusive statements on a roll of die

Tags: probability, bayesian

Let there be two people $A$ and $B$. Both have $0.5$ probability of speaking truth. I roll a die blindfolded. $A$ says $2$ has rolled and $B$ says $3$ has rolled over. Whats the probability of $2$ and $3$ being rolled over respectively

Now both of these have to be equal because of symmetry, but I want to understand the general concept of tackling these problems. I first thought $P(2)=0.5*(1-0.5)$ because it's the probability that $A$ spoke the truth and $B$ spoke a lie, but that means total probability becomes less than $1$ as $P(2)=P(3)=P(\neq2,3)=0.25$

In general even if there is no symmetry how do you go about tackling these problems

Comment: How can 2 and 3 both be rolled over ? I think you mean 2 **or** 3 ?

Comment: I think i should have added a respectively there

Comment: When $A$ lies about a die roll, is $A$ equally likely to state that any of the $5$ unrolled values came up?  Are the results independent?  For instance maybe $A$ always tells the true roll if an even number comes up, and always says $2$ came up when an odd number is rolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the assumptions that the die is fair,
and that a lying person will randomly choose one of the five wrong answers.

Taking the specific problem first, as there are $6$ equi-probable die outcomes,
I am leaving out the $\dfrac16$ factor for a particular outcome for simplicity.

P(A says 2 & B says 3 | die shows $2$) $= 0.5\times 0.5/5= 0.05$
P(A says 2 & B says 3 | die shows $3$) $= 0.5/5 \times 0.5= 0.05$
P(A says 2 & B says 3 | die shows $1,4,5,6$) $= 4\times 0.5/5 \times 0.5/5= 0.04$

Restricted probability sample space $= 0.05+0.05+0.04 = 0.14$

P(die actually shows 2) = P(die actually shows 3) $= \dfrac{5}{14}$

For the general case, taking the truth probabilities for A and B as $a$ and $b$,

P(A says 2 & B says 3 | die shows $2$) $= a(1-b)/5$
P(A says 2 & B says 3 | die shows $3$) $= b(1-a)/5$
P(A says 2 & B says 3 | die shows $1,4,5,6$) $= 4(1-a)(1-b)/25$

Restricted probability sample space $= [5(a+b-2ab) + 4(1-a)(1-b)]/25$

P(die shows 2) $= \dfrac{5a(1-b)}{5(a+b-2ab) + 4(1-a)(1-b)}$

Work out similarly for P(die shows 3)

Comment: This seems counter intuitive to me, the chances of a 2 flipping should be higher than if no statements were told as A spoke 50% truth. For example take B out of the picture and assume A told 50% truth. P(2) should simply be $0.5$ and dice shouldn't come in the picture.

Comment: Answer reviewed. paw88789 comments also very relevant.

Comment: Thanks for giving so much time. Now the answer makes sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome !